# Restrict size in interface for a custom base type, so that implementing custom type follows it

Tags: java

I want to define set of custom data types, eg. CountryCode, RegionCode, CategoryCode, XYZTypeCode etc (Similar to ISO Standard CCTS Type Code). I want to restrict that all of the code values should have maximum size of 6.So I defined an interface eg.

```
public interface CodeInterface{
    public interface Value{
  public char[] value= new char[6];
  public char[] listID = new char[8];
  public String listName = null;
  } 
 public List<Value> getCodeValues(); 
}
   ...
    public class Country implements CodeInterface{ 
        public List<CodeInterface.Value> getCodeValues() { 
            List<CodeInterface.Value> codeValues = new ArrayList<CodeInterface.Value>();
            CodeInterface.Value singleCodeValue = null;
            //Logic to get data from postgres DB....
            //Assign the code value
            singleCodeValue.content = (char[])resultSet.getString("CODE").toCharArray();
        }
    }
```

But the assignment has syntax error that "Final CodeInterface.Value.Content" cannot be assigned.
Please suggest a better and extendible approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a good way of solving it to be honest.

If I were you, I would go with an exception instead:

```
if (listName.length() > 6)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("CCTS too long.");
```

These strings are most likely hard-coded (there are finitely many such strings, and they probably won't change in a near future) so any error will most likely be in the code and caught in early testing.

Comment: Hi Aioobe,The interface compiles properly, but implementing class do not (as I mentioned above).

Comment: You haven't shown us the code. Where is `Final CodeInterface.Value.Content` and where is `singleCodeValue` declared for instance. Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: you can try the above code, just change the last line to assign value to content part. I have mentioned the declaration also in code:         CodeInterface.Value singleCodeValue = null;

Comment: The `Value` interface does not have a field called `content`, so I don't see how I can try that code.

Comment: Oops! please read singleCodeValue.content as singleCodeValue.Value.